# Android mute/umute not working properly on asus device

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am using `AudioManager` to mute unmute on *Asus memopad 10*. I can mute the device but i can't unmute it back. If i use some other application which uses microphone it also doesn't work there. Then i have to restart the device than it start working.

**Edti :** Mute code

```
_audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(mute);
```

Comment: You must be using buttons to press mute, and unmute. 

what error do you get when you press unmute? That is, if you get any error.

Comment: i am not getting nay error. and why the buttons?

Comment: How do you mute/umute?

Comment: You don't pass mute to that. You pass a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is the scenario, where you set the microphone to mute using a boolean and then use a button on screen to unmute it.

```
Boolean mute = true;
        final AudioManager myAudio;

        myAudio=(AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        myAudio.setMicrophoneMute(mute);
        Button unmute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.unm);
        unmute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myAudio.setMicrophoneMute(false);
            }
        });
```

Another scenario where you use the same button to mute or unmute :

```
public Boolean mute = true;
            final AudioManager myAudio;

            myAudio=(AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            Button unmute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.unm);
            unmute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myAudio.setMicrophoneMute(mute);
                if(mute=true){

                    mute=false;

                }
            else{

              mute=true;

                 }
                }
            });
```

Now everytime,the button

Comment: what difference it will make if i run the same code on button press?